# Batch Script for Team Foundation Server's Get method throws error when called via a program

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, batch-file, tfs

I use a batch script to automatically get and compile several solutions. Here is a sample snippet from the batch file:

```
"C:\...\IDE\TF.exe" get $/NG3rdParty/Main /recursive
```

This works fine when I call it from command prompt. However, I am writing a C# program to change the version numbers of DLLs, it does the following:

```
var businessFile= @"C:\Build\Common.AssemblyInfo.cs";

var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"http://tfs:8080"));
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(businessFile);
var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(tfs);
workspace.PendEdit(businessFile);
var batchFilePath = @"\CleanBuild.bat";
var batchFile = path + batchFilePath;


var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = batchFile, 
                UseShellExecute = true
            }
    };
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

When the batch file is called from program, the same line throws this exception:

`Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BATCH script has no way of knowing anything about workspaces you have declared in your C# code. If you start the Process in the local workspace directory, it should work:

```
var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = batchFile, 
                WorkingDirectory = "<local workspace dir>",
                UseShellExecute = true
            }
    };
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx